# Problems with displaying data on MS chart control

Tags: c#, visual-studio, charts

I am trying to create a line chart that shows test results over a period of time (interval of weeks). It's the first time I've used the chart control and I seem to keep displaying a grey square if I add points in from a loop:

[Like this http://imageshack.us/a/img69/4718/69sq.png](http://imageshack.us/a/img69/4718/69sq.png)

I just can't see where I'm going wrong in my code - if i add some generic points in by hand then it will display properly.

Here is the code I'm using:

```
    chtBreakdown.ChartAreas[0].AxisY.Minimum = 0;
    chtBreakdown.ChartAreas[0].AxisY.Maximum = 100;
    chtBreakdown.ChartAreas[0].AxisY.Interval = 10;
    chtBreakdown.ChartAreas[0].AxisX.IntervalType = DateTimeIntervalType.Weeks;
    chtBreakdown.ChartAreas[0].AxisX.Interval = 1;
    dtiStart.Value = DateTime.Now.AddMonths(-3);
    dtiEnd.Value = DateTime.Now;

    chtBreakdown.Series.Clear();
    DateTimeOffset minimum = dtiStart.Value;
    DateTimeOffset maximum = dtiEnd.Value;
    chtBreakdown.ChartAreas[0].AxisX.Minimum = minimum.DateTime.ToOADate();
    chtBreakdown.ChartAreas[0].AxisX.Maximum = maximum.DateTime.ToOADate();
    foreach (User u in allUsers)
    {
      List<Training> userTraining = u.TrainingList.Where(t => t.StartTime >= minimum && t.StartTime <= maximum).OrderBy(t => t.EndTime).ToList();
      if (userTraining.Count != 0)
      {
        Series series = new Series(u.DisplayName);
        series.ChartType = System.Windows.Forms.DataVisualization.Charting.SeriesChartType.Line;
        series.BorderWidth = 2;
        series.XValueType = ChartValueType.DateTime;
        foreach (Training t in userTraining) series.Points.AddXY(t.StartTime.DateTime, t.PassPercentage);
        chtBreakdown.Series.Add(series);
      }
    }
```

Can anybody show me where I'm going wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `Series` instances are probably not associated to any `ChartArea` by default. Try to add this:

```
series.ChartArea = chtBreakdown.ChartAreas[0].Name;
```